# How can I call instanceof by a reference to a class.

Tags: java

I'm working on a small database system just as a learning / because it seems fun project and ran into an issue for the database column type. The type is returned like so:

```
public final DataType getType() {
    return type;
}
```

Here's the DataType enum.

```
public enum DataType {
    BYTE(Byte.class),
    CHAR(Character.class),
    BOOLEAN(Boolean.class),
    SHORT(Short.class),
    INT(Integer.class),
    FLOAT(Float.class),
    LONG(Long.class),
    DOUBLE(Double.class),
    STRING(String.class);

    private final Class<?> type;

    private DataType(Class<?> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public final Class<?> getReferenceClass() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

However I'm trying to validate that the object being inserted into the column is of the correct type.

```
 public TableEntry put(int columnIndex, Object o) {
    Column column = table.getColumn(columnIndex);
    Class<?> c = column.getType().getReferenceClass();
    if(!(o instanceof c)) {

    }
    return this;
}
```

Whcih is the retuning the error "Unknown class c" and I'm very confused on how to go about this; Could anyone lend a hand?

Comment: @Juru - "Cannot resolve symbol `getClass()`"

Comment: O my bad. Didn't read the question through and my response was too fast. Thought c was not a Class object but a random object. Wanted to say c.getClass().isInstance(o) but c is already a Class object. Answer below is the correct one.

Comment: it might be possible that in some use cases, the class must match exactly. do `o.getClass()==c`

Answer (score 11):

The `instanceof` operator needs a type name in the source code to work properly, not a `Class` instance.

But because you have the `Class`, you can call [`Class`'s `isInstance` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-).

> Determines if the specified Object is assignment-compatible with the object represented by this Class. This method is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language `instanceof` operator.

```
if (c.isInstance(o)) {
```